# Catch "Could not open connection to gateway" in sshtunnel.py

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Every now and then setting up a tunnel using sshtunnel.py fails because the gateway (ssh_host) complains the first time I connect to it. I would like to give it a few retries before giving up:

```
for attempt in range(5):
    try:
        forwarder.start()
    except Exception, e:
        print 'Error (trying again in five seconds):\n' + format(e.message))
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        break
else:
    print 'Failed to setup a connection to the gateway'
    sys.exit(1)
```

However, the error is not 'detected'. I took a peek in the sshtunnel.py code and found that the [following](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/94c2bef94b59494a287fe07158baa103efefaab5/sshtunnel.py#L669) code catches the related Paramiko exception:

```
except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException:
    self.logger.error('Could not open connection to gateway')
    return
```

How do I catch this in my `try:`?

Comment: I'd consider that a bug in `sshtunnel.py`. You could create your own version that does a `raise` instead of `return` and send a bug report and diff to the developers. Its on [github](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/master/sshtunnel.py).

Comment: I created an issue on Github and got an answer real fast. See my answer for details. Thanks for you suggestion @tdelaney

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An SSHTunnel.py project member [advised](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/issues/37) me to add `forwarder._check_is_started()` to my code:

```
for attempt in range(5):
    try:
        forwarder.start()
        forwarder._check_is_started()
    except BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError as e:
        print 'Error (trying again in five seconds):\n' + format(e.message))
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        break
else:
    print 'Failed to setup a connection to the gateway'
    sys.exit(1)
```